# BreezeJs : many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, breeze

My entities are 'Books' & 'Categories'. Each book can have multiple categories, and each category can be related to several books.

To implement this I made the models like this :

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]        
    [DataMember]
    public Guid BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext is like this :

```
// Some code

public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Categories)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("BookId");
            x.MapRightKey("CategoryId");
            x.ToTable("BookCategoryMapping");
         });

 }

// Some code
```

At the client side, books entities doesnt contain any `categories` key ???

Im wondering if my model is correct.

the Table `BookCategoryMapping` has been created but it seems that i cant populate it with data using breeze.

How can I, using breeze, create a book entity and push categories into it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, EF can create a relationship between `Book` and `Category` by adding a row directly to the BookCategoryMapping table.  Breeze on the client cannot do that.  It can only create the relationship by creating a `BookCategoryMapping` entity, which will then be sent to the server when you call `saveChanges()`.

You will need to model `BookCategoryMapping` as an entity.